# WPF Extended Toolkit PropertyGrid - Expand all properties by default

Tags: c#, wpf, propertygrid, wpf-extended-toolkit

I am using the PropertyGrid from the Xceed WPF Extended Toolkit. Is there a way that I can make all properties expanded by default? Actually, I'll never need them to be "unexpanded" ever, so if the "un-expansion" (is there a word for that, BTW?) could be disabled, that would be even better.

Comment: I realise this isn't an actual answer, but have you seen Syncfusion is giving away their full suite ... https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense ... the benefit here is that they have their own forums where the technical staff answer questions directly. I have no affiliation to Syncfusion!

Comment: I meant to say Syncfusion includes a property grid!

Answer (score 2):

If you are still looking for a way to do this, I just figured it out myself.

```
private void PropertyGrid_SelectedObjectChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
{
    var grid = sender as PropertyGrid;

    foreach (PropertyItem prop in grid.Properties)
    {
        if (prop.IsExpandable) //Only expand things marked as Expandable, otherwise it will expand everything possible, such as strings, which you probably don't want.
        {
            prop.IsExpanded = true; //This will expand the property.
            prop.IsExpandable = false; //This will remove the ability to toggle the expanded state.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set IsCategorized="False" you will see all properties expanded by default:

```
<xceed:PropertyGrid IsCategorized="False" SelectedObject="{Binding}"/>
```

Also you can specify

```
ShowPreview="False" ShowSearchBox="False" ShowSortOptions="False"
ShowSummary="False" ShowTitle="False" ShowAdvancedOptions="False"
```

to disable all other parts than main property editor grid.

Answer (score 0):

```
_propertyGrid.ExpandAllProperties();
```